# Retrieve all instances of a custom Blazor component on a Blazor page

Tags: c#, blazor

I would like to get all the instances of a Blazor components on a Blazor Page:

Page:

```
<div class="mb-4 pt-3">
    <SearchFilter Refinement="@refinementAuthor" FilterTitle="Auteur"></SearchFilter>
</div>
<div class="mb-4 pt-3">
    <SearchFilter Refinement="@refinementSubject" FilterTitle="Onderwerp"></SearchFilter>
</div>
<div class="mb-4 pt-3">
    <SearchFilter Refinement="@refinementLanguage" FilterTitle="Taal"></SearchFilter>
</div>
```

How can I get a List of the three "SearchFilter"?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that currently such a feature does not exist in Blazor. You can, however, create a list of components by adding component references (@ref directive attribute) to a list object as follow:

### ChildComponent.razor

```
<h3>@Title</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

}
```

### Usage

```
<ChildComponent @ref="ChildComponent1" Title="ChildComponent 1"/>
<ChildComponent @ref="ChildComponent2" Title="ChildComponent 2" />
<ChildComponent @ref="ChildComponent3" Title="ChildComponent 3" />

@if (components != null)
{
   @foreach (var component in components)
  {
    <p>@component.Title</p>
  }

}

@code{
  ChildComponent ChildComponent1;
  ChildComponent ChildComponent2;
  ChildComponent ChildComponent3;

  List<ChildComponent> components;

  protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
  {
    if (firstRender)
    {
        components = new List<ChildComponent>();
        components.Add(ChildComponent1);
        components.Add(ChildComponent2);
        components.Add(ChildComponent3);

        StateHasChanged();
    }
   }

}
```

Note that the list is only populated after the page component is rendered. You can't access the components before as they are not yet created...